# Keydown Event Behaviour Not As Expected

Tags: javascript, tabs, focus, addeventlistener, keydown

I am using an event listener to monitor when `button 'c'` is pressed to activate a tab and a text input so that the user can start typing in it.

The behaviour I get instead is:

1.) When the correct tab is already active: The text input is correctly focused.

2.) When a different tab is active: The desired tab is correctly activated but the text input is not. If you press "c" again, behaviour (1.) happens.

Does anyone know how I get this to work so that when 'c' is pressed the tab is selected (if required) and the text input is focused as well.

I tried making the two functions sequential but I still get the same behaviour.

My code is as below:

```
            window.addEventListener (
                'keydown',
                function (event) {
                    if (!($(document.activeElement).is(":input"))){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        switch (event.keyCode){
                            //Key C
                            case 67:
                                $('#tabs a[href="#comments"]').tab('show');
                                $("#comment-box").focus();
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                },
                false
        );
```

Comment: To prevent c from being typed, you could experiment with writing `event.preventDefault()` somewhere at the top of your event listener.

Comment: Thanks Xufox works like a treat that.

Comment: Did you fix the code by editing the question? Solutions to problems are supposed to be posted as answers.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent “C” from being typed it’s necessary to include an `event.preventDefault();`.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(!($(document.activeElement).is(":input"))){
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      //Key C
      case 67:
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevents typing letter C
        $('#tabs a[href="#comments"]').tab('show');
        $("#comment-box").focus();
        break;
    }
  }
},false);
```

---

*Note: OP unfortunately edited the question to correct the code. His original revision didn’t contain the `preventDefault` statement.*